# Editing help sometimes mysteriously lacks LaTeX information

Tags: support, help-center, mathjax

On some sites, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help, there is help for LaTeX, and on some sites LaTeX information is mysteriously absent with no explanation. Why?

This can lead a user (like me) to believe that there is no LaTeX documentation on this site. This should be addressed.

Comment: Related: Mathematic's awesome *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)* (cross-site)

Answer (score 6):

Only some sites have LaTeX/MathJax enabled, so including information on how to use it in the Help Centers of sites where you can't use it would also be confusing. Thus its absence in some Help Centers.

A good solution would be to explicitly link to some help page on MathJax on the Ask Question page when MathJax is enabled on that site. This should also be done for *all* users while posting answers, since right now it seems to only be done for anonymous users who post answers (it says "Use MathJax to format equations. [MathJax reference](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)."). I know  have to consult a guide constantly for MathJax so I think this would be helpful for *all* users.

Comment: Also, we should add a note about how to find Latex info to pages like https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting , which is missing it

Comment: @cowlinator There is a link to the "advanced editing help page", that contains the "Latex info", at the top of the `/help/formatting` page you linked to.

Comment: Yes.  But there's nothing about "advanced editing help page" that would lead me to believe it has Latex info if the page I'm looking at doesn't even mention it.

Comment: Here, let's look at it another way.  As far as I can tell, everything on physics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting is related to markdown.  At the very top of the page, it clearly gives a link to Daring Fireball markdown.  My conclusion:  SE uses Daring Fireball for markdown.  Easy.  

Now, I go looking for latex info at physics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting .  I see that the whole page is devoted solely to Daring Fireball markdown.  I see that latex is not mentioned.  I see "advanced editing help page".  My conclusion:  "advanced editing help page" only contains advanced markdown.